# jQuery filling in hidden text input with one function

Tags: jquery

I have a piece of code but it is very long and unnecessary. I have tried improving it so that one function does the trick but I have been unsuccessful.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-one" />
    <input type="text" id="hidden-one" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-two" />
    <input type="text" id="hidden-two" />
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-three" />
    <input type="text" id="hidden-three" />
</div>
```

I am using a plugin that makes the checkboxes look nice and it comes with a method that returns true or false when the checkbox is checked or not checked. I would like the input below the checkbox to write out 'true' or 'false' depending on what state is checked. This works if I do a seperate method for each one but I want to bundle them all into one method.

State is the current state of the checkbox(true or false)

### My Attempt

```
$('.extras').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
    $(this).find('input').val(state);
});
```

This produces nothing. No errors or functionality.

### EDIT

I have checked how the plugin affects the DOM structure. Here is what it does to one of the form groups.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="bootstrap-switch bootstrap-switch-wrapper bootstrap-switch-animate bootstra-switch-off">
        <div class="bootstrap-switch-container">
            <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-on bootstrap-switch-primary"></span>
            <span class="bootstrap-switch-label"></span>
            <span class="bootstrap-switch-handle-off bootstrap-switch-default"></span>
            <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-one" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="hidden-one" />
</div>
```

Comment: is 'state' logging out the boolean correctly?

Comment: Yes if I do specify the method for just one of the checkboxes it logs it perfectly. However that adds many lines of code using a seperate method for each checkbox since I have about 10 currently.

Comment: The issue is that with $(this).find you are searching in the context of that element. The input is now outside of it's context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bootstrap plugin may change the dom structure in that case, you might have to use

```
$(".extras").each(function () {
    $(this).next().val(this.checked)
}).bootstrapSwitch();

$('.extras').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input:text').val(state);
});
```

```js
$(".extras").each(function() {
  $(this).next().val(this.checked)
}).bootstrapSwitch();

$('.extras').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
  $(this).closest('.form-group').find('input:text').val(state);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-one" />
  <input type="text" id="hidden-one" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-two" />
  <input type="text" id="hidden-two" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="extras" type="checkbox" name="extra-three" />
  <input type="text" id="hidden-three" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your current solution does not work, I inspected the developer console and edited my answer to include what the plugin does to my DOM structure.

Comment: I think there might be an error in your fiddle, nothing is logged to the input boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Without the plugin:

```
$('.extras').next().val($('.extras').prop("checked"));

$('.extras').click(function(){
        $(this).next().val($(this).prop("checked"));
 });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk04vpwj/2/)

Here's with the new DOM: The delegation sorts out the context issues.

```
$( ".form-group" ).delegate( ".extras", "click", function( event ) {  
  var elem = $(event.delegateTarget).find("input[type='text']");
  elem.val($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2m74k0y8/)